# TeXstudio is not loading *.cwl from document class

Tags: packages, texstudio, document-classes

So I have a modified document class where I use `\RequiredPackage` to load the packages into TeXstudio I need. The issue I have is that command does not trigger TeXstudio to load the associated `*.cwl` files as well. Basically, every command is not recognized but is correctly used when the document is compiled. I have read through the different answers and manuals but that has left me more confused then when I started.

How do I get TeXstudio to load the `*cwl` for the different packages I call in the document class? Conversely, if this is the absolutely worse way to do it, how should I set this up?

EDIT:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myDoc}[2019/07/01, v0.2]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}} 
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions* \LoadClass{article} \RequirePackage{siunitx}
```

I think the siunitx, ifthen, and calc cwl's should be loaded. When I compile, the siunitx commands are correctly interpreted but are unrecognized

EDIT 2:
The commands appear highlighted in red, and when moused over with the cursor, the popup window says "unrecognized command"

Comment: I do not understand, what you want. Why should TeXstudio load all classes, you use for a document? Maybe you could post a small example of your code? I also don't understand, what you mean with " I use `\RequiredPackage` to load the package into TeXstudio". ´\RequiredPackage´ is a command, it doesn't effect TeXstudio in any way.

Comment: ```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myDoc}[2019/07/01, v0.2]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{siunitx}
```
I think the siunitx, ifthen, and calc cwl's should be loaded. When I compile, the siunitx commands are correctly interpreted but are unrecognized

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand, what you want to know. But I am sorry, I don't know, if there is a way to trigger TeXstudio to use that file automaticly.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "TeXstudio does not recognize the commands"?

Comment: @schtandard The commands appear red highlighted, and when moused over with the cursor, are "unrecognized command"

Comment: Do you see that behavior in the document class file itself or in a different file that uses the document class?

Comment: I see the behavior in the main tex file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load a package or document class, TeXstudio does not look into the source of that package/class to figure out which `.cwl` files to load – it just load the `.cwl` file of that package/class.

This also holds for your class `myDoc`. When you load it, TeXstudio looks for `myDoc.cwl` in some places, doesn't find it and gives up. If you want TeXstudio to know which packages are loaded, you have to tell it by creating `myDoc.cwl`

```
#include:article
#include:ifthen
#include:calc
#include:siunitx
```

and saving it in the appropriate folder. On Windows, this is `c:\Users\<user name>\appdata\Roaming\TeXstudio\completion\user\`. You can find examples of how to write it in the adjacent `autogenerated\` folder.

---

The fact that you can compile just fine has nothing to do with all this. LaTeX will load the packages and execute the macro definitions therein regardless of if TeXstudio knows about it.

Comment: I assuming I will have to keep both the `myDoc.cwl` & `myDoc.cls` in sync?

Comment: Of course. TeXstudio does not monitor `myDoc.cls`.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem!! Here is the solution:

Add the command `\ProcessOptions\relax` at the end of your `.sty` or `.cls` file. Then reopen the cwl created by txs and you will find txs has already added all the `#include ...`commands automatically!!!